How to quantify the tone of a textual paragraph? If there is historical communication available, how to check for consistency in tonality for new i/p?
Certain aspects of NLP such as the basic Polarity, Subjectivity, and Positivity, can be obtained with ease, but keyword consistent usage and the "Style" or the "Tone" of writing cannot be well quantified to maintain the consistency which is helpful for brands in their marketing campaigns.
Tried to obtain different quantifiers, and get the aggregate values for the historical communications data, and ranging from this aggregated value would be an accept window, wherein if the new sentence/para lies within the range, it can be deemed consistent, but this is not working out well and lacks accuracy.

Have a look at the relevant research in stylistics and other fields of linguistics.
